# How can i pass data from mxsegmentedpager view controller to pager views

Tags: ios, swift

I am using [MXSegmentedPager](https://github.com/maxep/MXSegmentedPager) for my project and there is no examples. I want to pass a value to the pager view. How can I pass value from view controller to pager view controller without delegate?

i tried code i write here and it says

> "Could not cast value of type 'MXSegmentedPager_swift.MXWebViewController' (0x10915dae8) to 'MXSegmentedPager_swift.MXTableViewController' (0x10915da68)."

```
override func segmentedPager(_ segmentedPager: MXSegmentedPager, viewControllerForPageAt index: Int) -> UIViewController {
    var vc = super.segmentedPager(segmentedPager, viewControllerForPageAt: index)
    if index == 1
    {
        var vc = super.segmentedPager(segmentedPager, viewControllerForPageAt: index) as! MXTableViewController
        vc.a = "x"
    }
    return vc
}
```